# Bought a US appliance and powered directly off Aus mains, is it boned?

Tags: electrical, installation, appliances

Hope this is on topic for this stackexchange.

I recently bought a lamp from the US and had it shipped to Australia. Stupidly I powered it straight off the mains through an adapter. The device is rated at 120V 60Hz and Australian mains are 240V 60Hz. The lamp turned on for a split second and wouldn't power on at all after that. The device has a fuse in the back of it that appears to still be whole, the manual says this should be replaced if the lamp no longer dims correctly.

Have I written off the device or is it possible that it has remained intact? (I know it is impossible to say definitively but some information would be of great help)

Comment: I did this with a Dremel once. That was visually stunning.

Comment: +1 for introducing me to a new term that I will incorporate into my vocabulary directly, "boned"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does the device have a transformer or similar internal electrics?

If so there's a very good chance you've burnt it out. The fuse only protects against excess current - not incorrect voltage.

Comment: I'm not sure about the electrical internals, but it is a reasonably expensive and sophisticated lamp so it's quite possible. Since it is expensive is it worth taking it to a repairer to have a look?

Comment: @radman - it couldn't hurt. A decent place should look and quote for repair without charging you so you won't have lost anything.

Comment: Globetrotters should get a lamp with a 120-240 autoswitch power supply, which are plentiful now.  Many of them switch as far as 90-306V (Japan 100V minus 10%, American 277V plus 10%).